# Starting out with vote_fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Trying my luck with the [vote_fu rails plugin](http://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu/tree#readme). The functionality looks like exactly what I need for a project of mine, but I have hit a roadblock. I have followed the github readme to the letter, installing it as a plugin.

I have put acts_as_voteable on my "Event" model and acts_as_voter on my User model.
In the console, when I try:

```
>> event.votes
```

or

```
>> user.votes
```

it successfully returns an empty array.

but when I try to do the following:

```
user.vote_for(event)
```

I get

```
"NoMethodError: undefined method `user_id' for #<Vote:0x7f5ed4355540>"
```

Any ideas? I'm probably just missing something obvious, but maybe something is missing from the plugin's readme.

Thanks.

[Update]

I created a blank application and the plugin works fine, so I think that this problem might be being caused by the use of the "desert" plugin, as my User class is split over two files. If I find the answer, I'll post it so that in the off chance someone else runs into this it may be some help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I haven't found a definitive reason why this problem occurred, but I do have strong suspicions that it is due to the use of the "desert" plugin, as my User class is split over two files (the project is using the [CommunityEngine](http://communityengine.org/) plugin as a base),

Anyhow, I found a work around (something I should have tried before posting here). Instead of installing vote_fu as a plugin, I installed it as a gem. And now vote_fu seems to be humming along nicely.

So let that be a lesson to you all!

:-P